# Loading configuration items from another config file in CI

Tags: php, codeigniter, configuration

I've been trying to load a configuration item into another configuration file for my CodeIgniter app.
The reason for doing this is that I don't want to go through all of the files to change same parameters when I, for example, change the server or want to change the site title.

I've tried to get the items I need from the main `config.php` file by using `$this->config['site_title']`, by loading the config file using `$this->config->load('config')` and by loading individual config item using `$this->config->item('site_title')` but all of these methods return errors that the configuration items could not be loaded.

Am I missing something?

Comment: To load a file inside another file, you'll have to use include 'file.php' and use the variables directly, I cannot see it working otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

you should load the config files from the CI instance within a Controller

`$ci = & get_instance();`

`$item_name = $ci->config->item('item_name');`

Answer (score -1):

simply create your config file in your ci config folder

```
myconfig.php
```

in it

```
$config['my_site_title'] = 'TechNew.In - www.technew.in';
```

and load your config in the controller

```
$this->load->config('myconfig');
```

then get your value

```
$my_site_title = $this->config->item('my_site_title');
```

Comment: Config files cannot load other config files inside them.